# An example of function that is not constant but its derivative is 0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Let $U \subset R^{n}$ be and open set. Let $f:U \to R^n$ be a differentiable function.

I wonder if there is such a function that is not constant but with $Df=0$ at every point. (The derivative is 0).

Comment: Well, if $U$ is not connected you could define a function to be 1 on one of the connected components and 0 on the others.  But if $U$ is connected that implies $f$ is constant; and in general, $f$ has to be locally constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider $f$ defined on $\mathrm{U} = \mathbf{R}^2 \setminus\{(x,0) : x\in \mathbf{R}\}.$ Here $\mathrm{U}$ is the plane minus the $x$-axis. Define $f = (0,0)$ on the upper part of $\mathrm{U}$ and $f = (-1,0)$ on the lower part.

Answer (score 2):

Let $U = (0,1)\cup (2,3)$ and $f: U \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $f(x) = 0$ for $x \in (0,1)$ and $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in (2,3)$. For open and connected sets $U$, $Df \equiv 0$ implies that $f$ is constant (I can provide a proof if you want).

Comment: Thanks Nicolas!

Comment: About the case where $U$ is connected and open, can I prove it with the multi variable version of the Newton Leibniz fundamental thorem?

Comment: If $U$ is connected and open and $x, y \in U$, you can compose a diferentiable path from $x$ to $y$ with each of the coordinate projections of $\Bbb{R}^n$ onto $\Bbb{R}$ and then deduce the result from the case when $n = 1$ (where it follows from the mean value theorem).

Comment: Could you explain what are the coordinate projections? And how can you use this theorem from a multi dimensional domain?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I proved it by fixing $x_0 \in U$ and considering the set $D := \{x \in U: f(x) = f(x_0)\}$. Since $U$ is connected, it suffices to show that $D$ is open, closed and non-empty. Since $x_0 \in D$, $D$ is non-empty, and since $D = f^{-1}(x^0)$ and $f$ is differentiable (and thus continuous), $D$ is closed. Show $D$ is open by considering $x \in D$, then there exists $\epsilon > 0$ such that $B_\epsilon(x) \subset U$. Use $Df \equiv 0$ and consider $\phi(t) = f(xt+(1-t)y)$ for $t \in [0,1], y \in B_\epsilon(x)$ to show $B_\epsilon(x) \subset D$.

Comment: I'm only in the third semester though so there might be something shorter